# IDLE for Python 3.3 doesn't start and does not give an error message

Tags: python-idle

I cannot start IDLE from my shortcut or from `Start > All Programs > Python 3.3 > IDLE (Python GUI)`.
When I click on it, nothing happens. I tried running as administrator; nothing either... It was working fine a few days ago.

I can run it if I go to `C:\Python 33\Lib\idlelib\_main_` (However a black python command line stays open and if I close it, IDLE closes as well.)

I'm using a 64-bit release of Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use any othere mode file name to instead of sys mode? ex. I meet the same issue, after check, there is one 'string.py' when i do a test about Relative paths and an absolute path, so, when idle start, it always load wrong 'string.py', after i delete it which create by myself, it can work now.